# Is there a microcontroller kit that ships with development tools for Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, compatibility

I was looking around on the web for an introductory kit with a USB-based microcontroller that I could get started on.

However, most of the tools I looked at were Windows-only.

Are there any kits designed for Ubuntu, or at least ones for Linux that work well in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [arduino](http://arduino.cc/).

Comment: One small question... can any of the boards be connected via USB? When I was looking through the wiki, it seemed like they connected through a serial port.

Comment: They are all USB, to my knowledge.  Some of the smaller or older ones require a separate USB to serial adapter called an FTDI board.  I would recommend starting with the Arduino Uno, which has everything right there on the one board.

Comment: Finally got my Arduino - absolutely love it!

Comment: have you also tried Picaxe? It is small and super low power...and CHEAP too. But I also like the Adruino too!!